# Checking a string to see if a specific grouping exist (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, string

situation: A user inputs a user name and password. now the user enters a user name called Game_Admin. Thus tries to imitate being a head power of the site and scam others.

At the moment My log in script check for Length Characteristics, and to see if it already exist. My question how do I go about checking to see if a player enters a specific grouping of characters in our example the grouping i am trying to stop duplication of is "Admin". So If the word Admin ever appears whether it is (myAdminaccount ,pizzaAdmin, GreatestAdmin). I am wondering would I use a loop of some sort to search through each user name character by character or is their another easier way?

Than you everyone for your suggestions Indeed there are many ways to go about this situation. I hope this topic can be a good reference for others who decide to use type if check. I am putting them all to the test and weighing out my options but I believe I have found the solution that works best for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest when a user signs up, check the username against a blacklist before accepting form submission. If you're using off-the-shelf software it probably supports this.

Test on PHP [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) when form validation takes place:

```
$badlist = Array(
  'admin',
  'staff',
  'official'
);

foreach($badlist as $badword){
  if (strpos(strtolower($_POST['username']), $badword)!==FALSE)
    die('fail');
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thank you for your help AL, indeed this method seems to be exactly to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [stristr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) for case-insensitive string matching:

```
<?php
  $string = 'TehAdmin';
  if(stristr($string, 'admin') === FALSE) {
    echo '"admin" not found in string';
  } else {
    echo '"admin" found in string';
  }
  // outputs: "admin" found in string
?>
```

For extra entertainment, you can use [`str_ireplace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) to replace occurrences of admin with the empty string:

```
<?php
$string = str_ireplace("admin", "", $string);
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

Comment: the str-ireplace could be a comical gag i could use but atm it isn't exactly what I am looking for but thank you for this great method.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this.  I would use [stripos](http://php.net/stripos) (case-insensitive):

```
$findme    = 'admin';
$mystring = 'This is a fake string';

$pos1 = stripos($mystring, $findme);

// Nope, 'admin' is not in $mystring
if ($pos1 === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
}
```

Comment: I think stripos() is better for this application because he's only looking to see if it *ever* appears in a string.  stristr() looks for every occurrance and so is needlessly slower if you don't need that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can use one of several functions to determine if one string contains another, stristr() and preg_match() are common ones to use.

```
$input = 'Game_Admin';

if ( FALSE !== stristr( $input, 'admin' ) )
{
  // whatever
}

if ( preg_match( "/admin/i", $input ) )
{
  // whatever
}
```

Although I'm concerned that you appear to be assigned roles to users based on substrings of their username.  That's not a great way to about this.  It's better to have roles and permissions defined in the database.

Comment: They're not actually assigning roles, they just want to stop people trying to *impersonate* admins in order to social engineer.

Comment: ah ok, I get it.  I missed that nuance.